# limiting which rows are selected - mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to set the LIMIT value for a query depending on what link the user clicks.

This code checks if a user clicked the link and sets the values accordingly:

```
if(isset($_GET['page']) && $_GET['page']>0){
    $y = $_GET['page'];
    $upper = $y * 10;
    $lower = $upper - 10;
    $limit = "$lower,$upper";
}
else{
    $limit = "0,10";
}
```

For example if the link is `"index.php?page=1"`
the limit would be `0,10`.

If the link is `page=2`
the limit would be `10,20`

The query:

```
$sql = mysql_query("select * from comments order by time desc limit $limit") or die (mysql_error());
```

For some reason it doesn't select the rows I want.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: what rows does it select?

Comment: Have you tried to execute the query on your MySQL DB directly instead of through PHP? What does it output?

Comment: page=1 selects 10 rows as intended, page = 2 selects 20 rows, page 3 selects 22...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It isn't "lower, upper."  It's "offset, number of rows."  That means that you want the pattern

1. 0,10
2. 10,10
3. 20,10
4. 30,10

and so forth.

Answer (score 1):

Your pagination logic is wrong.

Read the manual of [LIMIT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html) clause:

> With two arguments, the first argument specifies the offset of the
>   first row to return, and the **second specifies the maximum number of
>   rows to return**. The offset of the initial row is 0 (not 1):

```
$page = isset($_GET['page']) && $_GET['page'] > 0 ? $_GET['page'] : 1;

$per_page = 10;
$offset = ($page - 1) * $per_page;
$limit = "$offset, $per_page";
```

Answer (score 0):

The second parameter of LIMIT is the number of rows you want the query to return. If you want to select a maximum of 10 rows each time, you should fix it at `10`.

```
if(isset($_GET['page']) && $_GET['page']>0){
    $y = $_GET['page'];
    $lower = $y * 10 - 10;
    $limit = "$lower,10";
}
else{
    $limit = "0,10";
}
```